# error occured while click on table in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

pop-up

some errors have been detected on the server please look at the bottom of this window.

---

Notice in `./libraries/structure.lib.php#1881`
 Undefined index: Rows

Backtrace

```
./libraries/structure.lib.php#2382: getHtmlForRowStatsTable(
array,
NULL,
boolean false,
boolean false,
string '',
string '',
)
./libraries/display_structure.inc.php#263: PMA_getHtmlForDisplayTableStats(
string '',
NULL,
NULL,
boolean false,
NULL,
string '?db=SD&amp;table=sdLogin&amp;token=9d4015ef2a6184f763cb956b670ca8af&amp;goto=tbl_structure.php&amp;back=tbl_structure.php',
NULL,
)
./tbl_structure.php#163: require_once(./libraries/display_structure.inc.php)
```

Comment: it's working after delete and recreate thanks

Comment: Good to here that. Can i write it as a solution and you mark it? So that other can get help?

Comment: yes you can write your ans here

Comment: What version of phpMyAdmin are you running?

Comment: @stack please up-vote the answer for others help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems any one of two problem occurring in your case:-

1. Either at the time of installation some problem occur because of that when you are clicking on table this error occur.
2. either there is some problem at the time of table or database creation.

Solution:-

1. first try to delete table and try to implode or recreate it.
2. If not success then try to do the same with its database and then create table.
3. If again not successful,then try to create another table and check same error happening or not?
4. If yes then uninstall your xampp/wamp/lamp and reinstalled and check.

Answer (score 0):

Delete database you have created and try to create again.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you have uppercase characters in the tables' names. If you change their names to lowercase, the problem will be gone.